# Open a dijit.calendar on an specific month but having no date selected

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm having a very specific problem with the dojo toolkit whose answer I could not find on the api or the docs. I have a standalone calendar on my page, it is instantiated by

```
var myCal = new dijit.Calendar({
                                    'value':            new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000),
                                    'title':            'Title',
                                    'isDisabledDate':   function(data){
                                        var dat =   new Date(data);
                                        dat.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                                        var ms  = parseInt( (dat.getTime()/1000), {'places':0});
                                        return (GERA.palestras.diasComPalestras[ms] !== true);
                                    }
     }, "mycal");
```

This does work, the calendar is created, it is at the correct month/year and have a date selected. I want to do just that, BUT, without the date selected. So I want to pass to the calendar an year and a moth to display on the page **but without selecting a date**. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know your post is a bit old.

I have been needing something similar.
Looking through the documentation, there is a attribute called "currentFocus" which is supposed to do exactly what you are saying. Also do not set value to anything, and it will be unselected.

```
var myCal = new dijit.Calendar({
                                'currentFocus':            new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000),
                                'title':            'Title',
                                'isDisabledDate':   function(data){
                                    var dat =   new Date(data);
                                    dat.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                                    var ms  = parseInt( (dat.getTime()/1000), {'places':0});
                                    return (GERA.palestras.diasComPalestras[ms] !== true);
                                }
 }, "mycal");
```

However, I personally have not gotten this to work, I was wondering if you have had any progress since you posted?

EDIT:This actually does work. I just had something else clobbering the change later on from my parser.

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the question being asked, please try using a comment next time...

Comment: Sorry @Barett   new to the game so no comment privileges, yet. Also, its been fixed, so now it is an answer.

Comment: Going to try it and if it works I will mark as answered. Thanks mate. Old or not,I still have not fixed it